# how do i get a layer's frame to automatically resize based on its superlayer's frame or its view's frame?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation, calayer

I'm experimenting with using cagradientlayer to draw gradients in our app instead of having a subclass of uiview manage gradients.  One snafu that i've come across is that when the view that has the gradient as a sublayer of its main layer gets resized to fit the data i am trying to show, the layer doesn't resize along with it.  I end up having the gradient layer end at the original frame size while my view's frame is much larger.

Is there a way to have the sublayer autoresize to fit its superlayer's frame, or the superlayer's view's frame?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Implement [layoutSubviews](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/layoutSubviews) in the subclass of your view.  It gets called when the frame is resized (or when setNeedsLayout is called).  Just set the layer's frame to the view's bounds:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    someSubview.frame = self.bounds;   // make the subview frame match its view
}
```

Comment: I'm hoping to not need a subclass at all, but some functionality that may exist in CALayers that i can't seem to find that would do this for me (subclassing a layer is not out of the question though).

Comment: How are you resizing the view?  I resize views by setting the frame and have never had to resize the layers.

Comment: i'm setting the frame in some cases, and letting the view get autoresized in others.  i think the problem might be that when i resize the views manually i turn off autoresizing of subviews so that the subviews themselves don't resize; that might be my problem.

Answer (score 2):

This will work even better

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
```

Comment: Better than what? And why? Please make sure to provide complete answers.

Comment: Better in that it will actually do what is intended here, I think.

Comment: At the time I asked this question, i dont think UIViewController had that method. I do agree that if your views are stock views managed by a uiviewcontroller that you would want to do this instead of layoutSubviews in a UIView subclass.

Comment: Make sure you hit that 'like' button then, if you like my answer. Helps a bunch. Cheers.